# Postgres UNION: not showing the full number of rows from both tables

Tags: postgresql, union

I needed to export an ESP report in two chunks (split by timeframe) because of the size and I wanted to import both reports into postgres and combine them into one table. (All column names and column orders are the same). While I was able to import both reports as separate tables into postgresql, when I run a union, it seems like 103k rows were lost.

Here's the query I used:

```
select *
from all_email_opens_by_date_range_feb_to_may
union
select *
from all_email_opens_by_date_range_june_to_sept;
```

And the result shows 1,019,378 rows. 
However, the table "all_email_opens_by_date_range_feb_to_may" has 625,142 rows and the table "all_email_opens_by_date_range_june_to_sept" has 497,759.  Since 625,142 + 497,759 = 1,122,901, I was expecting the union to display 1,122,901 rows.  Can someone please explain how my union could discard 103k rows? I don't have much experience with unions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `union` removes duplicates. Maybe you want `union all`?

Comment: that did the trick! Thank you a_horse_with_no_name